# angularjs fomly - error with vars in templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I can't display model or other variables in my template - http://jsbin.com/wofulinufo/edit?html,js,output.

question: how fix for display variables from controller?

if I write `{{model}}` or `{{vm.model}}` - it don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were overwriting your model with `vm.model = {}`. Here's your example now working: https://jsbin.com/pivevu/edit

Note, it is `{{model}}` because the template is compiled with the `formly-field` scope, not your controller's scope. See [this example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates)